# Optimally reordering cards in a wallet?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, hash, language-agnostic, linked-list

I was out buying groceries the other day and needed to search through my wallet to find my credit card, my customer rewards (loyalty) card, and my photo ID.  My wallet has dozens of other cards in it (work ID, other credit cards, etc.), so it took me a while to find everything.

My wallet has six slots in it where I can put cards, with only the first card in each slot initially visible at any one time.  If I want to find a specific card, I have to remember which slot it's in, then look at all the cards in that slot one at a time to find it.  The closer it is to the front of a slot, the easier it is to find it.

It occurred to me that this is pretty much a data structures question.  Suppose that you have a data structure consisting of k linked lists, each of which can store an arbitrary number of elements.  You want to distribute elements into the linked lists in a way that minimizes looking up.  You can use whatever system you want for distributing elements into the different lists, and can reorder lists whenever you'd like.  Given this setup, is there an optimal way to order the lists, under any of the assumptions:

1. You are given the probabilities of accessing each element in advance and accesses are independent, or
2. You have no knowledge in advance what elements will be accessed when?

The informal system I use in my wallet is to "hash" cards into different slots based on use case (IDs, credit cards, loyalty cards, etc.), then keep elements within each slot roughly sorted by access frequency.  However, maybe there's a better way to do this (for example, storing the k most frequently-used elements at the front of each slot regardless of their use case).

Is there a known system for solving this problem?  Is this a well-known problem in data structures?  If so, what's the optimal solution?

(In case this doesn't seem programming-related: I could imagine an application in which the user has several drop-down lists of commonly-used items, and wants to keep those items ordered in a way that minimizes the time required to find a particular item.)

Comment: Searching through a list to find a specific item is an O(n) operation - which is about as optimal as it gets. Dividing it into k list (providing you can know which list to look in) makes it O(n)/k which is insignificant for n>>k. Putting more frequently accessed items at the front of the list effectively reduces n.

Comment: @Dale- While that's true, you could imagine some sort of splay-tree like algorithm that gives good *amortized* performance even if individual lookups are slow.  You could also design a data structure that makes high-priority elements accessible very quickly by making sure they're not too deep in the linked lists.  The fact that you can't do better than O(n / k) in the worst-case doesn't necessarily mean that it's the best that you can do for all access patterns.

Comment: @templatetypedef- Sure, however, you have to work out if the overhead of maintaining the list is less than the saving.

Comment: @Dale M- Oh, absolutely.  The whole point of this question is to see if there is a legitimate scheme that works out better than the simple distribute-elements-evenly system.  I hope there is!

Comment: @templatetypedef- A low overhead algorathm would be to move the just accessed item to the front - frequently accesed items would stay near the front while less accessed ones would fall back. The overhead is basically nil - you've already found the item so moving it to the front is a snap and you don't need to keep any data access stats

Comment: wrt my comment above - this is only true of an in-memory data construct. If it needs to be persisted (like in a RDMS or a wallet) it could play merry hell with your indexes and/or fingers.

Comment: In case 2 (no advance knowledge of the probability distribution), to get a better bound than O(n/k) I think it would be necessary to assume that there is a stationary (but unknown) distribution of item requests.  Then a dynamic data structure (e.g. lists with MTF) will ideally gradually converge on the best configuration.  The bounds will be related to the entropy of the distribution: the more uneven the request probabilities, the better you could hope to do.

Comment: Years ago, I remember seeing an old paper on this topic for the simpler case of k=1.  I *think* it was called something like the "file location problem" (from the days when files were physical *things* that were stored on shelves!) but I haven't been able to turn up anything with a few Google searches :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although not a full answer for general k, [this 1985 paper by Sleator and Tarjan](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~sleator/papers/amortized-efficiency.pdf) gives a helpful analysis of the amortised complexity of several dynamic list update algorithms for the case k=1.  It turns out that **move-to-front is very good**: assuming fixed access probabilities for each item, it never requires more than twice the number of steps (moves and swaps) that would be required by the optimal (static) algorithm, in which all elements are listed in nonincreasing order of probability.

Interestingly, a couple of other plausible heuristics -- namely swapping with the previous element after finding the desired element, and maintaining order according to explicit frequency counts -- don't share this desirable property.  OTOH, on p. 2 they mention that an earlier paper by Rivest showed that the *expected* amortised cost of any access under swap-with-previous is <= the corresponding cost under move-to-front.

I've only read the first few pages, but it looks relevant to me.  Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at skip lists. There is a similar problem with arranging stations for a train system where there are express trains and regular trains. An express train stops only at express stations while regular trains stop at regular stations and express stations. Where should the express stops be placed so that one can minimize the average number of stops when travelling from a start station to any station.

The solution is to use stations at ternary numbers (i.e., at 1, 3, 6, 10 etc where T_n = n * (n + 1) / 2).

This is assuming all stops (or cards) are equally likely to be accessed.

Comment: In this case each linked list corresponds to express station 'N' and the regular stops that follow it until the next express station.

Comment: I'm familiar with skip lists, but unfortunately that's not how my wallet is organized. :-) I know that there are a lot of good linked lost variants out there, but in this question I was hoping to focus on optimal algorithms that could potentially be used in the real world.

Comment: If you know the probability of accessing elements beforehand you can develop an ordering using something similar to the huffman coding techniques.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the access probabilities of your n cards in advance and you have k wallet slots and accesses are independent, isn't it fairly clear that the greedy solution is optimal?  That is, the most frequently-accessed k cards go at the front of the pockets, next-most-frequently accessed k go immediately behind, and so forth?  (You never want a lower-probability card ranked before a higher-probability card.)

If you don't know the access probabilities, but you do know they exist and that card accesses are independent, I imagine sorting the cards similarly, but by number-of-accesses-seen-so-far instead is asymptotically optimal.  (Move-to-front is cool too, but I don't see an obvious reason to use it here.)

Perhaps you get something interesting if you penalise card moves as well; if I have any known probability distribution on card accesses, independent or not, I just greedily re-sort the cards every time I do an access.